# Why does my Kobalt KST 2540-06 weed eater stop every minute?

Tags: battery, lawn, grass

My Kobalt KST 2540-06 weed eater will only run for a minute and then stop. I release the trigger and then squeeze it again and it starts running again only to shut off after about a minute. No matter how many times I do this it keeps stopping after about a minute. Any ideas?

Comment: Has it ever worked right?

Comment: Probably overheating, or battery reaching end of life. Or battery reaching end of life and overheating.

Comment: bad contact in the trigger

Comment: It's a battery operated trimmer. Is the battery charged? I can always get a few extra turns out of my cordless drivers when the battery is dead by waiting a few moments and squeezing the trigger again - the battery can give one little burst of energy, but doesn't have enough for continuous running. Also, if it's under warranty, just bring it back! (Unless it's just a dead battery.)

Comment: if you want root-cause why, it's probably because it's a cheap Kobalt trimmer.

Answer (score 2):

Likely, there is a thermal switch, which shuts the motor if it gets hot. However, the motor should run quite cool unless there is undue friction.

- Look for something wound around the motor shaft. Some possibilities:

  - Some of the nylon cutting line
  - Grass trimmings
  - Debris such as a plastic bag
- Check if the line reel is rubbing on the guard.
- Check that the right type of line is used.
- Check if there is damage to the reel, causing it to rub.

See the [manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1838684/Kobalt-Kst-2540-06.html?page=18#manual) for cleaning out debris.

Note that this trimmer has a 5-year warranty -- take it back, if applicable.